# Drag out generated binary from HTML5 Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, file-io, drag-and-drop

I created a small binary stream with the BlogBuilder. And now I want to get a way for the user to save it on the desktop. Is there anyway (dragging, anchor, ...) to do this without a server?

I have the latest Chrome and Firefox Beta and it is not important that one of these dosn't support a solution (is an experimental case).

I tried already to drag a file from the browser to the filesystem, but there was no example to do that with an generated file.

I got an file download via the Chrome File API, but that sandboxed and I don't know where the file is (o: Is there maybe a way to use the File API, create the file in the sandbox and offer that file as download link for the user?

Thank you so far, I hope you can help me.